# Dynamics AX 2009: Batch Trouble with AsciiIO class

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics, axapta

I have a custom class, we'll call it FileProcessUpload and it extends RunBaseBatch. It more or less creates a CSV file and then uploads it to an FTP server. When the class is run manually, everything works fine. However, when submitted as a Batch Job, there is an error in the infolog stating "AsciiIO object not initialized".

Probably the most important thing to note here is that this Batch Job is being delegated to a different AOS.

Here is a cropped down version of the offending code:

```
void CreateFiles()
{
    #File
    AsciiIO             asciiio;
    FileIOPermission    permission;
    ATable              aTable;
    str                 outputFile;
    str                 directory;
    ;
    directory       = @'C:\Uploads';
    ouptutFile      = directory + @'\output.csv';

    if (!WinAPI::folderExists(directory))
    {
        WinAPI::createDirectory(directory);
    }

    // Try to assert the appropriate file access mode
    permission = new FileIOPermission(outputFile, #io_write);
    permission.assert();

    // Try to open the file for writing
    asciiio = new AsciiIO(outputFile, #io_write);
    if (asciiio != null)
    {
        while select aTable
        {
            // Write the necessary lines into the file
            asciiio.write(aTable.field1 + ',' + aTable.field2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        error('Could not create file: ' + outputFile);
    }
    // Close file and release permission assertion
    asciiio = null;
    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();

}
```

Comment: I can confirm that I have only one problem with the provided code: WinAPI class methods cannot be used on server: `The server-side impersonated (RunAs) session tried to invoke a method that is available for client-side processing only.`

Apart from it, everything is ok: the file has been created, text written.

Comment: I also was able to confirm your observations here. After just creating a folder on the server with the appropriate permissions and ignoring this "create it if it doesn't exist" logic, it started to run properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the service user that Ax is running under have permissions to read/write the file?

You are using the *WinAPI* class, but should you be using *WinAPIServer* class instead?  You may be executing on the server of course.

Do you need to add to your class the following *public boolean runsImpersonated() { return false; }* and run this class on a client?

Good luck

**Edit:** Executing your code via the *server static void mainOnServer(Args args)* method signature is commonly used (see PurchFormLetter class for it's usage) to make sure that you execute on the server.  It is called from *static void main(Args args)*

Comment: The service user that is running the batch job does have local admin write privileges on the AOS that is running the job. The job is **definitely** running on the server.

Currently, I do not have an accessor method for runsImpersonated, but ideally this should run as the server.

Comment: OK...  Just as long as your really *do* have a 'C' drive on your server then ;)  I have EXACTLY the same process as you do running and have chosen to use the Windows temporary directory instead, guaranteeing that the base path exists - http://axandhellisfunafterall.blogspot.com/2011/08/that-windows-temporary-directory-that.html

Comment: I did try your suggestions of using _WinAPIServer_, and overriding **runsImpersonated**. I'm still getting the same error message though. I just can't seem to nail down what the problem is.

Comment: (Sorry, my 5 minutes to edit timed out) I wrote this as a class first, and once I got it working correctly, I started adapting it as a _batchable_ class. It still runs when run locally, but I'm constantly getting the error about **"AsciiIO object not initialized"**.

I know this is an older class (AsciiIO), but I really need the ability to write out an ASCII file. It still seems like it's permissions or like I'm missing a property somewhere.

Comment: Just a note: I've tried the temporary path route also, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem for me. Could you perhaps provide the mandatory minimums to insure that a class will run on a server in a batch?

Comment: Creating a _server static void mainOnServer(Args args)_ method signature is commonly used (see PurchFormLetter class for it's usage) to make sure that you execute on the server.  It is called from _static void main(Args  args)_  ...  Can you use the [TextIO class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa881745(AX.50).aspx) and pass in a code page to the constructor?  I'm clutching at straws, here - 10p says that your code works (without the _runsImpersonated_ method), just not on your server machine!

Comment: Your second sentence in the original answer above is technically the correct "answer". Using WinAPI in a server-run batch job turns out to be a no-no. Now I have another question, marking this as resolved and opening a new thread for that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use file path and file name instead of str as directory and name
2. If runbasebatch then should put pack/uppack filePath and fileName and put it into currentVersion control at classdeclaration.
3. If you move/delete/encrytion/read file, using system.io.file /system.io.stream, or streamreader, or system.net.ftpwebrequest, and system.net.ftpwebresponse, remember to run on server static void method for this...

Any file format I have done, txt, .csv, .gpg, I move around file easily in/out ax to other server, no problem to just write a file inside of AX by fellowing the above rule..